# Uploading files fails sometimes - check this user agent string

Tags: html, http, file-upload, user-agent

I am developing a webapp where I allow users to upload documents. It is working well for most users but for a few (2-5%) the upload does not work. What I hear is that the upload just does not finish, it keep uploading forever - even for small files like 100Kb.

The actual upload page can be seen under step 2 here:
[My upload page example](https://www.jobmatchprofile.com/backend/login.aspx?auto_login=TST4A4&language=ENU)

I have never seen the problem myself and have not been able to re-create it (tested in many versions of IE, Chrome, FF, and Safari). Not sure it even has to do with browser version. What I have is this from one user who experienced the problem

```
(Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; FunWebProducts; BTRS31753; GTB7.4; .NET CLR 1.1.4322))
```

How do I interpret this, guess it is IE7 but what more can I pull out, and does anything here indicate problems.